# HADOOP_HOME is not set correctly

Tags: hadoop, installation

I downloaded the binary tarball of hadoop from here: http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html (ver 2.8.4). I unpacked the tar.gz file and then changed the etc/hadoop-env.sh from

`export JAVA_HOME={$JAVA_HOME}`

to my java jdk locaction:

`export JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

I also added these two lines:

`export HADOOP_HOME=D:/hadoop/hadoop-2.8.4
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin`

But when i try to run

`$ hadoop version`

from cmd i get an error message that says

`Error: HADOOP_HOME is not set correctly`

What did I do wrong and how should I change the hadoop_home path for it to work?

Comment: I think the slashes must be backward in $HADOOP_HOME if it's in windows( You have used forward slash "/"). Forward slash separator is used in Linux, not windows.

Answer (score 0):

Other than `{$JAVA_HOME}` has the dollar sign in the wrong spot (needs to be outside the brackets), Windows doesn't run the shell script to locate your variables

You need to set environment variables in Windows from the Control Panel. And you also need to remove all spaces from the file path of "Program Files"

Its not clear if you're using Cygwin or using Windows Linux subsystem, but it's different from the native CMD

Answer (score 0):

Set the path HADOOP_HOME Environment variable as below:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=D:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.4
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME\bin

$ hadoop version
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

I come across such error when I try to use **hadoop-3.3.1**, the latest version. I have searched a lot about "HADOOP_HOME not correctly set" and there are no useful results.
But after I downgrade to hadoop-3.2.2, this error disappears.

I think you can try the non-latest version again.